# reducing Java Garbage Collection for methods returning arrays?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

Object A has method B(), and lives for most of the life of the application.  B calls object C method D().  D() returns an array holding up to x MyData objects.  MyData might be a POD (plain old data)/PDS (passive data structure) or might be more, but a MyData can be reused by calling methods or setting fields; its identity or functionality isn't cast in stone during construction or otherwise.

Currently B() is defined like:

```
class A {
  public B() {
    MyData[] amydata = c.D( 5 );
       :
       :
  }
}
```

Currently D() is defined like:

```
MyData[] D( int iRows ) {

    MyData[] amydata = new MyData[ iRows ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < iRows; i++ ) {

        if ( no more data )
            return amydata;

        amydata [ i ] = new MyData();

        // calculate or fill in MyData structure.
    }

    return amydata;
}
```

A is going to be always, or for a long time (e.g., until the user reconfigures it) be asking for the same number of rows, even though the data will differ.

So what if I have the caller pass in the array reference:

```
class A {
  int iRequestSize = 5;
  int iResultSize;
  MyData[] amydata = new MyData[ iRequestSize ];

  public B() {
    iResultSize = c.D( iRequestSize, amydata );
       :
       :
    // use up to iResultSize even though array is potentially bigger.
  }
}

// returns number of rows actually used
int D( int iRowsMax, MyData[] amydata ) {

    for ( int i = 0; i < iRowsMax; i++ ) {

        if ( no more data )
            return i;

        if ( amydata [ i ] == null )
            amydata [ i ] = new MyData();

        // calculate or fill in MyData structure.
    }

    return iRowsMax;
}
```

I'm a C++ guy and new to Java, but it seems that assuming MyData can be recycled like this, the second version should avoid creating and copying MyData's, as well as eliminating garbage collection?

Comment: It all depends on environment and the size of the array. For most cases I would give preference to readability over the performance.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the second variant is worse.

In the first variant `amydata` and all the objects referenced by it can be garbage collected as soon as the method `B()` exits (assuming that B doesn't store a reference to `amydata` somewhere else.)

In the second variant `amydata` cannot be garbage collected as long as the instance of `A` lives.

Consider the case where upon the first call to `D()` it returns 5 references to `MyData` objects, but on subsequent calls it returns no more rows. In the first variant the `amydata` array and the 5 referenced `MyData` objects can be garbage collected as soon as `B()` returns. But in the second variant neither the `amydata` array nor the 5 `MyData` objects referenced through it can be garbage collected - possibly never during the whole runtime of your application.

Remember: the Java Garbage Collector is optimized for many short-lived objects

Comment: > "In the second variant amydata cannot be garbage collected as long as the instance of A lives."  EXACTLY.  THE ENTIRE POINT OF THIS QUESTION IS WHETHER THIS MINIMIZES GC!  Thanks for answering my question, even though you seem to couch it as a negative...  >"in the second variant neither the amydata array nor the 5 MyData objects referenced through it can be garbage collected - possibly never during the whole runtime of your application"  DANKE!  GENAU MEINE ZIEL!  :-D

Comment: @SwissFrank obviously, you are "a C++ guy". You are making your code inefficient by requiring it to perform additional checks (like whether there is already an object in the array), to trick something that has been well optimized during the last 25 years. In the end, the effect of your "optimization" is the opposite. The garbage collector has to *traverse the reachable objects*, to identify them as reachable. Hence, the more objects you keep alive artificially, the longer does the garbage collection cycle need. Further, the gc does not free dead objects, but *copy survivors* to a new place.

Comment: @SwissFrank only do it if you can prove that it helps you. Your way of preallocating the datastructures works against basic assumptions built into the JVM (garbage collector and JIT compilation) as well as assumptions built into the Java standard libraries. Garbage collection times increase with the number of live objects, and if the remainder of your code produces garbage (maybe by calling standard Java utility classes), a local optimization will not stop the garbage collection from occurring, but make the garbage collection pauses longer.

Comment: > "Garbage collection times increase with the number of live objects"  OK, but won't the frequency of GC become far less?  Granted I may not be able to eliminate it but if I cut new object  creation 100-fold, will GC not become more rare?

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer:*** Reading the OP's comments, I have to admit that I didn't get his real intent, i.e. to develop a soft-real-time application, avoiding garbage collection as much as possible, a very special and rare situation in the Java world.

*So the following answer does not match his problem. But as a casual reader migrating from C++ to Java might stumble over this question and answer, he/she might get some useful hints on typical Java programming style.*

---

Although the syntax of Java and C++ have quite some similarities, because of the very different runtime environments, you should adopt a different coding style.

As a decades-long Java guy, I'd surely prefer the original method signature. As a caller of the `D()` method, why should I create the results data structure instead of getting it from the method I am calling? That reverses the natural flow of data.

I know, in good old C times when dynamic memory management meant lots of headache, it was very common to prepare the result array outside of the function and have the function only fill in the results, the way you wrote the second version. But forget about that with Java, and just let the garbage collector do its job (and it's very good at that job). Typically trying to "help" the GC results in code that's in fact less efficient and harder to read. And if you really want to stick to that style, there's no need to pass both the max rows number and the array, as the array itself knows its length (that's different from old-style C arrays), giving the max row number.

You assume

> the second version should avoid creating and copying MyData's

That sounds like a misconception about Java's inner workings. Every time you execute a `new MyData(...)` expression, you create a new instance somewhere on the heap. Providing a `MyData[]` array doesn't avoid that. Translated to C terminology, the array just holds pointers to `MyData` objects, not the real objects. And Java instances are hardly ever copied (unless you explicitly call something like `object.clone()`). It's just the reference (= pointer) to the instance that gets copied when you assign something to a variable.

But even the first version is far from perfect, if I understand its purpose correctly. The `D()` method itself can determine when there's no more data available, so why should it return an array longer than necessary? With Java arrays that's a bit inconvenient, so typical Java code returns a `List<MyData>` in similar situations.

One more comment on the `MyData()` constructor and later "calculate or fill in MyData structure". I know that style exists (and is quite popular in the C family of languages), but it's not predominant in Java, and I especially dislike it. To me, it sounds like asking "Give me a car" and getting just a skeleton instead of a usable car. If I want it to have wheels, an engine and seats, I later have to supply them myself. If a usable car needs the selection of options, I want to supply them when ordering the car / calling the constructor, so that I can honestly call the result a car instead of a skeleton.

And finally a comment on the Java naming conventions: the vast majority of Java code follows the conventions, so your method names beginning with upper case look very strange to me.

Comment: > "As a caller of the D() method, why should I create the results data structure instead of getting it from the method I am calling?"  I supply a postbox the post office puts mail in.  I take a bag to the grocery to put the groceries in.  It's not odd on its face.

Comment: > "there's no need to pass both the max rows number and the array, as the array itself knows its length"  You didn't study the problem.  The result set's maximum length is immutable, however the app may want less than that.  For instance, a web site may have the option to show you your shopping history either 10 or 40 items per page.  The array might be then hardcoded to 40 items long, so that it never needs reallocation no matter which users take which option, while the number passed in may be 10 or 40 based on user preference.

Comment: > "just let the garbage collector do its job (and it's very good at that job)"  You're basically saying not to do what I'm trying to do.  With respect you don't know my application domain.  It's soft real time.  We are going to minimize GC.  End of that discussion.

Comment: > "typical Java code returns a List<MyData> in similar situations"  Understood.  The caller needs the array-type random access to elements.  ArrayList<> appears to share C++ vector<>'s shortcoming of periodically having a far longer addition operation, due to the array outgrowing allocated memory, and re-allocating and copying itself.  In any app where you're minimizing GC to keep performance predictable, ArrayList<>, unless I'm wrong about that, wouldn't be a good choice.  (Unless I pre-allocated it... which is in effect what I'm doing instead.)

Comment: > "Every time you execute a new MyData(...) expression, you create a new instance somewhere on the heap. Providing a MyData[] array doesn't avoid that." How does it not do that? The only new in the second example is executed at startup, and as it's not freed until shutdown, there's no GC on it or its constituents. One new for the array, and at most one new per element of that fixed size array, per execution of the binary sounds like less than the same amount of work per call to D().

Comment: > "To me, it sounds like asking "Give me a car" and getting just a skeleton instead of a usable car"  You're confusing the container (the garage, that I probably put a succession of cars in) with the parts of the car itself (which in this case the caller doesn't assemble or modify; D() does those and B() only looks at them).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that you want to use Java in a real-time application "without dynamic memory" (my wording). That's a huge challenge! I hope you succeed, as you'll have to do everything on your own, carefully avoiding library calls that might create garbage. One more hint: there are Java runtimes with really non-blocking garbage collectors, targeting real-time scenarios.

Comment: GC is not totally unacceptable.  The goal is simply to have as little as possible.  I understand that the more live data there is, the longer the marking phase can take.  But GC (at least in the older collectors I'm reading about) only starts when a segment of memory is used up, and if we can avoid using it up, then we will have far fewer GCs.

Comment: The problem with GC and real-time is that typical GCs block the whole VM for some part of the time. As long as the GC runs as a non-blocking parallel thread, it won't hurt more than any other of the VM's demon threads. So, I'd really recommend to have a look at e.g. JamaicaVM, relieving you of some headaches.